# Ruby How to assign new value to array in hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have a hash where each value is an array and am having trouble updating location 1 in the array as needed. My code is below.

```
newOrderItem = STDIN.gets.chomp

while newOrderItem != "q"
  if items.has_key?(newOrderItem) == true
    print "How many #{newOrderItem}'s would you like?"
    qty = STDIN.gets.chomp
    items[newOrderItem[1]] = items[newOrderItem[1]] + qty
    puts "Please enter the item you whish to order. Enter \"q\" when you have finished."
    newOrderItem = STDIN.gets.chomp
  else
    puts "Sorry, #{newOrderItem} is not on our menu. Please try again."
    newOrderItem = STDIN.gets.chomp
  end
end
```

The line where I think I am in trouble is "items[newOrderItem[1]] = items[newOrderItem[1]] + qty" When I run this program, I get an undefined method error on the plus sign. What I would like to do is have the qty added to the current value (always an int) in the array for that key. My hash looks like this.

```
items = { 'Hamburger' => [3.65, 0], 'Fries' => [1.00, 0], 'Drink' => [1.49, 0], 'Shake' => [2.25, 0], 'Chicken Nuggets' => [0.99, 0]  }
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: joerdie, it's perfectly OK for you to say, "I'm a Ruby newbie", but try to avoid having your code scream that out in the very first line.  I'm speaking of the variable `newOrderItem`, which does not conform to Ruby's [naming convention](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_names.html). :-)

Comment: Underscores instead of camel case for a local variable? Meh. And putting a smiley at the end of something does not make it come across as less condescending.

Comment: I did not mean it to be condescending. I just wanted you to know that 99.9% of the Ruby code you will read will conform to a particular style, that includes indentation (2 spaces), naming of variables and methods, and so on.  If you want to deviate from that, that's your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you get an undefined method error, since `items[newOrderItem[1]]` returns `nil`.
To access the hash you should use `items[newOrderItem][1]`, which looks for the key `newOrderItem`, then finds the array and returns the element at index 1 of the array.

As well as this when you do the addition on line `items[newOrderItem[1]] + qty` `qty` is still a string.You must convert it to a numerical type first, use `Integer(qty)` if you want to convert it to a non-decimal value, or `float(qty)` if you want a decimal numerical value. So you would have something like this `items[newOrderItem[1]] + Integer(qty)`.

Eg:

```
2.0.0-p353 :019 > items = { 'Hamburger' => [3.65, 0], 'Fries' => [1.00, 0], 'Drink' => [1.49, 0], 'Shake' => [2.25, 0], 'Chicken Nuggets' => [0.99, 0]  } 
 => {"Hamburger"=>[3.65, 0], "Fries"=>[1.0, 0], "Drink"=>[1.49, 0], "Shake"=>[2.25, 0], "Chicken Nuggets"=>[0.99, 0]} 
2.0.0-p353 :020 > items['Hamburger'][1]
 => 0
```

Comment: Thank you. This is my final line. items[newOrderItem][1] = items[newOrderItem][1] + Integer(qty) and it works perfectly. Thank you.